# PHPExcel: Read .xlsx file, sum column 'x' values for similar value of column 'y'

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel-1.8.0

I'm stuck on this problem, let me explain. I've a Excel sheet that has 3 columns like so:

```
y       x       z
10      5       0
10      5       4.25
10      5       0
30      2       0
30      2       1.85
30      2       0
```

How can I add the values of col.x for the similar values of col.y?

The desired result is:

```
y=10, x=15
y=30, x=6
```

Is it possible to achieve this using PHPExcel (if not then what's the best approach)?

I tried this but its returning  associative array:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_name);
$array = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $array->getHighestRow();

$data = $array->rangeToArray("A2:C$highestRow");
```

$data returns associative array, but that's not what I want.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of using it as a excel file try using csv file. It stores data as multidimensional array. Then search for position of different variables and add them up. That is pretty easy!!!

Comment: thanks but I need to do it using excel(.xlsx) only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need walk the array data and sum the items manually

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_name);
$array = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $array->getHighestRow();

$data = $array->rangeToArray("A2:C$highestRow");

$sumData = [];
foreach ($data as $row){
    $key = $row[0];
    if(!isset($sumData[$key])){
        $sumData[$key] = [0, 0];
    }
    $sumData[$key][0] += $row[1];
    $sumData[$key][1] += $row[2];
}

print_r($sumData);
```

Result:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [10] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 15
>             [1] => 4.25
>         )
>
>     [30] => Array
>         (
>             [0] => 6
>             [1] => 1.85
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Comment: thanks! what if we also want sum of col.z as well. For e.g. `y=10, x=15 & z= 4.25`?

Comment: if this solution works for you please check as resolved, thanks